# UIImagePickerController Causes my app to crash!

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

In my app, a user can select an image, change the picture of a UIImageView to the new imge, and save the image to NSUserDefaults using NSKeyedArchiver.  When the user selects the image and the `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` is called, the app immediately crashes!  Xcode recieves the error: SIGABRT. Here is my code -

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PictureKey"] == 1) {
        UIImage *previmage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        [prevbutton setImage:previmage];
        NSData *previmagedata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:previmage];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:previmagedata forKey:@"PrevImage"];
    } else if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PictureKey"] == 2) {
        UIImage *nextimage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        [nextbutton setImage:nextimage];
        NSData *nextimagedata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:nextimage];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nextimagedata forKey:@"NextImage"];
    }else {
        UIImage *optionsimage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        [moreoptionsbutton setImage:optionsimage];
        NSData *optimagedata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:optionsimage];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:optimagedata forKey:@"OptionsImage"];
    }
}
```

And here is my error.

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
2010-04-16 18:09:25.012 iPimpYourMusicApp[2815:6807] Failed to save the videos metadata to the filesystem. Maybe the information did not conform to a plist.
2010-04-16 18:09:49.009 iPimpYourMusicApp[2815:207] *** -[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1180
2010-04-16 18:09:49.016 iPimpYourMusicApp[2815:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIImage encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a1180'
2010-04-16 18:09:49.026 iPimpYourMusicApp[2815:207] Stack: (
    864992541,
    859229716,
    864996349,
    864492313,
    864454720,
    854367759,
    854367021,
    854365681,
    27619,
    841224192,
    857776904,
    857868032,
    857637052,
    839607712,
    839985680,
    854089611,
    864740547,
    864738335,
    875880904,
    838872112,
    838865456,
    11173,
    11068
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
[Switching to thread 11779]
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Don't laugh at the name of my app being iPimpYourMusicApp - I had no idea what to name it, so I joked around and named it that... :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would improve your chance of getting an answer if you put details such as where and how your appliaction crashes. For instance which line, debug log, etc.

Comment: Sorry about that... I fixed it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly archive a UIImage - UIImage doesn't implement NSCoding.  You have to use one of the `UIImage[JPEG|PNG]Representation` to convert it to a NSData object.

So you code would look like:

```
UIImage *optionsimage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
[moreoptionsbutton setImage:optionsimage];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(optionsimage) forKey:@"OptionsImage"];
```

Getting the image back out would require the inverse:

```
UIImage *optImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dataForKey:@"OptionsImage"]];
```

HTH!

-Stephen